# Extracting multiple fields from json output

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

Hi folks im new to asking questions in stack but I want to know what is the process in order to remove the 'name' value from the json output below i know how to get the individual names through indexing`name = [groups['groups'][0]['name'] for groups in result]` but how do i get both names

```
from pyzabbix import ZabbixAPI

import json

z = ZabbixAPI(url='https://zabbix.server,user='xxxx',password='xxxx')
result = z.host.get(output='groupid',selectGroups='extend', filter={'host' : 'mailpphfprd01'})


name = [groups['groups'] for groups in result]

name
```

Json Output:

```
[[{u'flags': u'0',
   u'groupid': u'110',
   u'internal': u'0',
   u'name': u'- GSOC - Systems'},
  {u'flags': u'0',
   u'groupid': u'313',
   u'internal': u'0',
   u'name': u'Applications - Email Digest'}]]
```

Required output

```
[u'- GSOC - Systems' u'Applications - Email Digest']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it with a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
json_output = [
  [
    {
      "internal": "0",
      "flags": "0",
      "groupid": "110",
      "name": "- GSOC - Systems"
    },
    {
      "internal": "0",
      "flags": "0",
      "groupid": "313",
      "name": "Applications - Email Digest"
    }
  ]
]

names = [d['name'] for d in json_output[0]]

print(names)  # -> [u'- GSOC - Systems', u'Applications - Email Digest']
```

Comment: `json_output[0]` why is the index placed here is it to represent the internal []

Comment: The json output is a list of a list of dictionaries, so I just hardcoded the index of the first entry in the outer list — in other words, `json_output[0]` is the first (and only) entry of that outermost list.